# Do multiple loops have same complexity as nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

This for loop has a complexity of **O(n)**

```
for ($i=0; $i < $arrCount - 1; $i++) { }
```

And this 2 nested for loops have a complexity of **O(n^2)**

```
for ($i=0; $i < $arrCount; $i++) { 
  for ($j=0; $j < $arrCount; $i++) { 
  }
}
```

But what if I did 2 for loops inside a function and they just folowed each other, no nesting

```
for ($i=0; $i < $arrCount; $i++) { 
}
for ($i=0; $i < $arrCount; $i++) { 
}
```

Would the function still be executed in **O(n)** ?

Comment: It would still be O(n).  2 * O(n) = O(n).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes.**

Nested loops means that the outer loop will execute the inner one completely for each iteration (of the outer). This means `O(n^2)` in your case, because for each `i` from `0` to `n` we do `n` operations.

```
i = 0 => inner loop runs n iterations
i = 1 => inner loop runs n iterations
...
i = n - 1 => inner loop runs n iterations
```

`n` iterations `n` times means `n^2` total iterations, so `O(n^2)`.

Your 2 loops without nesting will each iterate `n` times, for a total of `2n` times. [Big-oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ignores constants, so `2n = O(n)`.

Since they are not nested, the number of times each one runs will not depend on the other. So you add the number of iterations, not multiply them.

Comment: Hello, the above question is similar to my situation. Different is, in my case the two loops is iterated with different numbers. For example, `$arrCount0` and `$arrCount1`. Note that `$arrCount1` >> `$arrCount0`. If these loops follow each other as stated in the question, will the complexity be `o(m)+O(N)` in my case?